# If you kill a boss in dark souls 2 with someone by being summoned, is that boss defeated in your own world?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I can't find any summmon signs in Dark Souls 2, so I was wondering, could that boss could be defeated if I got summoned?

Answer (score 5):

No, bosses defeated while you are summoned as a phantom are not counted towards your own world's progress.

Answer (score 0):

No. The boss is only gone in the world's master eyes. When you defeat a boss as a phantom/shade, you are teleported your world to where you were in your world when summoned, with full estus, HP, and spell uses.

This can be use to be fully prepared for a boss in your world!